# Require Stack / MODULE_NOT_FOUND error when running sudo pm2 start server.js

Tags: node.js, nginx, mongoose, pm2

I'm new to NGINX. I am trying to run my Node server with `sudo pm2 start server.js` but I keep on getting MODULE_NOT_FOUND requireStack error. Everything's fine when I run it to a local machine but when I run on nginx, this keeps happening. I can't connect to my backend. Please, help.

[image]

I'm not sure if this will help, but when I also run `node server.js`, I also get this error.

[image]

Comment: Looks like a permission issue. The user under which pm2 is running doesn't have access to your folders and that is why it is not working.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer, but it's working now. I uninstalled mongoose, then re-installed it. :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! I uninstalled mongoose `npm uninstall mongoose` and re-installed it `npm install mongoose`.

Comment: yeah exactly, but not mongoose in my case, it was pm2. I ran `npm uninstall pm2` and `npm install pm2 --save-dev`. Just check what's after /node_modules/.. and re-install it.

Answer (score 1):

1. I had the same issue I forgot to run npm install before running pm2.
2. Even if you are running a build file, please run npm install.